# Error: mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql

Error: mysqli_stmt::get_result()
PHP: PHP: 7.0.8

I was thinking that this is about the PHP version. The host that my friend is using is pretty basic and does not have a option to change it on Cpanel

```
<?php
        $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE region = "1"  ORDER BY id DESC ');
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
```

That's the line where it fails on.
Am I right to think that ? Or is something else going on.
If it is the version do I need to contact the host ?
The wierd thing is it works on my own free hoster..

Sorry for the lack of information guys S: New here...

Comment: There's no way we can help you with so little information. Please share some code.

Comment: tell the php version and all other stuff you are writing...

Answer (score 1):

You are using Mysql Native and it is required to `Mysql Native Driver`

You should read [Mysql Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php) and [mysqli_stmt::get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: Alright thanks for the information. Only problem is that I am a noob... So I see alot of information I have no idea how to use or where to use.